# How can I paste links and transpose at the same time?

Tags: excel

I have a long list of titles along the top of a sheet, that I want to turn into a vertical list on another sheet but which is linked to the original list.  Basically I want to paste links into another sheet but tranpose it at the same time.

The Paste Special allows me to paste links, or paste the transposed range as formulas or values (not as links), but does not not allow me to do both at the same time as the Paste Links button is greyed out when the transpose option is ticked.  What is the easiest way to achieve the same output?

Input (Sheet1) - a row of numbers:
[image: Excel screenshot 1]

Desired output (Sheet2, formula view) - a column of links:
[image: Excel screenshot 2]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Perhaps it is version specific? What version of Excel are you using?  The versions I have used all show an option for `All`, which includes the links. (Excel for Windows 2007, 2016, O365)

Comment: It's when the Transpose box is ticked that the Paste Links button is deactivated.  I want to be able to paste links but turn the row of cells into a column.

Comment: If I tick the `Transpose` box, the links are also transposed.  Or if I tick the `Paste Special` entry (down at the bottom of the box, a dialog opens where you can `Transpose` `All`. Perhaps if you provided an example of your data, and your expected results, your issue would be more clear to me.  Include how you are creating the links.

Comment: Thanks Ron.  I have added screenshots to my original question to try to show an example of data and results.  The links are to other cells in the workbook and created by pressing "Paste Links" in the Paste Special dialog box.  In the screenshot, I have manually moved the cells into a column shape but ideally this could be done by using transpose function.  I have also tried transposing after pasting links but then the link references move relatively.  Is there a way to paste links with absolute references?

Comment: I misunderstood.  You want to paste links to the original cells, not links that are within the cell. I don't believe you can do that the way you want.  But you could do it with a formula.  eg:  `=TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!C3:G3)`

Answer (score 0):

In C3 of Sheet2, just put this and drag downwards should do :

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$3,0,ROW()-3)
```

Idea : use cell's row numbers as reference 'column shifter'.

Please share if it works/not. ( :